# Gridsplitter and Touch

Tags: wpf, xaml, touch, gridsplitter

I am using a GridSplitter to resize columns (what else :)). Works fine.
However, I am evolving in a Surface V2 environment and if I use touch simulation the Touch events are not transmitted to my dear GridSplitter.

Any hint on how to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

Just register the event like this:

```
YourGridSplitter.PreviewDragEnter += new DragEventHandler(YourGridSplitter_PreviewDragEnter);

void YourGridSplitter_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   // nothing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the touchdevice.

```
gs.PreviewTouchDown += (s, e) => { e.TouchDevice.Capture((s as UIElement)); };
```